# how can i use english as system language in comb. with metric values?

Tags: language-support

not pleased with the german translations in ubuntu phone aquaris 4.5 version 11 .Hence would like to use english. However military time, celsius and meters instead of miles would be nice...

Comment: It will soon be easier to [separate language and formats](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1392699) on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I set Engligh (UK) as language and I have metric units in my Meizu Pro 5.

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.

Comment: System Settings>Language & Text>Keyboard layouts>English (United Kingdom)

Comment: @jaezcurra: Nope. Keyboard layout is something else. You probably meant Language.

Comment: Yes, you are right: Language & Text>Display language>English (United Kingdom).
I do apologize...